# Using facebook login in android app(no errors in logcat)

Tags: android, facebook, layout

I am a beginner android programmer.I was trying to add a facebook login page into my android app.I made a class which is supposed to display the login page..
but when the line reaches **setContentView(R.layout.fblogin);** the program stops and there is no error in the logcat..so I cant understand the problem with the login page.Please help

Here is my Facebook login activity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookCallback;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.appevents.AppEventsLogger;
import com.facebook.login.LoginResult;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;


 public class FbActivity extends Activity{
  private CallbackManager callbackManager;
  private TextView info;
  private LoginButton loginButton;
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    try {
    setContentView(R.layout.fblogin);

    info = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.info);
    loginButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);

FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
// AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);
callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();


loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
        info.setText(
                "User ID: "
                        + loginResult.getAccessToken().getUserId()
                        + "\n" +
                        "Auth Token: "
                        + loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken()
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        info.setText("Login attempt canceled.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException e) {
        info.setText("Login attempt failed.");
    }
});

 }catch (Exception e)
   {
     e.printStackTrace();
   }

    }


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
 }


}
```

This is my login layout-**fblogin.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:padding="16dp"
>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/info"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    />

<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
    android:id="@+id/login_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    />
```

And this is my Manifest file

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 package="com.pioneer.admin.digitalmenu" >

 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    >
   <!-- android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >-->

    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.pioneer.admin.digitalmenu.LoginPage"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges=
            "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />

    <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider1234"
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
        android:exported="true" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.pioneer.admin.digitalmenu.MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.pioneer.admin.digitalmenu.FbActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"></activity>

    <activity
        android:name="com.pioneer.admin.digitalmenu.FeedBack"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>


    <activity
        android:name="com.pioneer.admin.digitalmenu.PrintDialogActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
</application>
```

Thanks..

Comment: properly add facebook sdk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code:

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext()); put it before      

setContentView(R.layout.fblogin);
```

Answer (score 1):

> You should init `Facebook` your `SDK` before `setContentView` as per Newer `Facebook` `SDK`.

**Change this.**

```
 setContentView(R.layout.fblogin);

 info = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.info);
 loginButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);

 FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
```

**To this.**

```
 FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
 setContentView(R.layout.fblogin);

 info = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.info);
 loginButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
```

> Also it seems looking your `onActivityResult` without `super`.

**Change this.**

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
 }
```

**To this.**

> `Override` it with `super`.

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

Comment: Appreciate my answer if it helped you.